# discord.py Dsiplay guild's icon using icon_url

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to get the guild's icon url. How do i use icon_url to grab the link?

```py
@client.command()
async def servericon(ctx):
    await ctx.send(discord.Guild.icon_url)
```

I expected to get guild's icon url, but got "property object at 0x000002683BB548B8" this instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the property of the class, you need to use the property of the instance that represents the specific guild you're interested in.  In you case, this will probably be `ctx.guild.icon_url`

Comment: Hey thanks, I will definitely try this one. Btw, I used `@client.event` and that worked